# Location Manager does not update the location in iPad, but it is working in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cllocationmanager

earlier The following code worked properly in iPad & iPhone both.
but after some times same code does not working in iPad. The issue is iPad always showing same location(Latitude,Longitude), if i am not on that location.

```
-(void) getLocation
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    if ([CommonFunction checkForLocationService])
    {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        strLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
        strLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

i have already added Location Privacy Key in info.plist file.

Comment: Just a guess, please check if you've statically added the lat and long. in code...probably for testing purposes

Comment: no, i have not added static.

Comment: on your iPad, check if the app has been authorised to use the iPad's location.

Comment: yes everything checked

Comment: I'm really sorry for a delayed reply but if you haven't yet found a solution, you could have a look at: https://www.appcoda.com/how-to-get-current-location-iphone-user/

Comment: Here is another useful link:https://www.devfright.com/location-authorization-ios-8/ Download sample code: https://www.devfright.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/LocationAuth.zip

Answer (score 2):

First:

Your code is wrong. Never ask the location manager for its location. Implement the delegate method and receive location updates there. You only need to tell the location manager to start updating locations ONCE. The delegate method will be called repeatedly.

Second:

Location determination is not magic. It uses the device’s internal hardware. Your iPhone and your iPad have very different internal hardware.

Your iPhone is a phone. It can use cell towers and GPS to determine its location. Thus it knows where it is pretty much all the time.

Your iPad doesn’t have any of that hardware. It is not a phone and it has no GPS.  It has to guess where it is by making a WiFi connection and looking up the router location in an online database. It can do that only under special circumstances. The rest of the time, it doesn’t know where it is.

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn’t say anything about iPads. I talked only about the OP’s actual iPad. I’m suggesting his iPad does NOT have GPS.

Comment: Never ask the location manager for its location means i did not get . @matt. i also used delegate method though it didn't working

Comment: All I know is the code you showed, and the code you showed is wrong